# How to generate dynamically column and row like a displayed in a below image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-design

How to create UI as in a images

[image]

I am creating a app where teacher and student can interact with each other and teacher can get a list of student and concept as shown in a images.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Warm regards,